# Intellij issue while importing sbt project

Tags: intellij-idea, sbt

I cloned a github repo and trying to import it in Intellij.But it gives me error as:

> 

```
[error] java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jetbrains.sbt.CreateTasks$
  [error]   at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
  [error]   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
  [error]   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
```

Scala plugin version is:2017.2.13

Comment: Aked here too:https://gitter.im/ThoughtWorksInc/DeepLearning.scala

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to upgrade your IntelliJ and the Scala plug-in?

Compute.scala uses sbt 1.1, which is not supported by your IntelliJ version.

See https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-12901